# JavaFX Non-Responsive/Very Slow on Low End Embedded System?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to implement a simple JavaFX GUI - Meaning a few buttons, a text area, a few circles (as lights) and a few labels.

Note that none of the functionality for these items has been created yet. So all these items are essentially hollow. Note this is my first JavaFX application (I've always worked in Swing).

So running in Eclipse on my i7 laptop has no problems and runs flawlessly. When I try to run it on the target machine (specs below) I get about a 15 second long non-responsive window. Once the gui comes up, any clicks on any elements in the window causes ~10seconds of CPU spiking up to 50ish%.

Once again there is no code behind any of the buttons or lights or text area yet. Is JavaFX just not meant to be on such a low end system?

Specs:
Windows Embedded 32bit (6.1)
Intel Atom E680 @ 1.6Ghz
2GB Ram
DX11
Atom E6xx Embedded Media and Graphics

Code is below if anyone needs it.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    // Initialize GUI

    gui = RecorderFXApplication.getGUIInstance();
    guiCtrl = gui.getFXMLController();
}
```

Application:

```
public class RecorderFXApplication extends Application
{

    /**
     * Standard error logger for log4j2
     */
    static Logger errorLog = LogManager.getLogger(RecorderFXApplication.class.getName());

    private static RecorderFXApplication instance = null;

    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

    public RecorderFXApplication()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/RecorderGUI.fxml"));

        try
        {
            Pane root = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(root));
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.titleProperty().set("Faceboss Database Recorder");
            instance = this;

        } catch (IOException exception)
        {
            errorLog.error("Error loading fxml for view: " + exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception
    {
        super.stop();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * @return the instance
     */
    public static RecorderFXApplication getGUIInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Application.launch(RecorderFXApplication.class);
                }
            }).start();
        }
        while (instance == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                errorLog.error("Error getting instance " + e);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RecorderFXController getFXMLController()
    {
        while (fxmlLoader.getController() == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                errorLog.error("Error getting controller " + e);
            }
        }
        return fxmlLoader.<RecorderFXController> getController();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public class RecorderFXController implements Initializable
{
    /**
     * Standard error logger for log4j2
     */
    static Logger errorLog = LogManager.getLogger(RecorderFXController.class.getName());

    @FXML
    private TextArea logWindow;

    @FXML
    private Button startRecButton;

    @FXML
    private Button stopRecButton;

    @FXML
    private Button pauseRecButton;

    @FXML
    private Button exportButton;

    @FXML
    private Circle redLight;

    @FXML
    private Circle yellowLight;

    @FXML
    private Circle greenLight;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)
    {

    }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074652/core-java/javaone-2012-javafx-graphics-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: Thanks for the interesting read. Not sure exactly how it helps. I can include my fxml if that will show how simple the app is. Also I am using CSS but there are only about a dozen different items. But again, at this point, none of the items are being changed or modified.

Comment: Have you tried a more naturally structured version of your application? I find the way how you instantiate the application with all the threading highly suspicious.